# Heroic 500 error but not on local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am deploying to heroic and it was successful but when I went to the heroic url I got a 500 error. Here is my log file

```html
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106733+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <tbody>
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106735+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <% @users.try(:each) do |user| %>
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106736+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:           <td><%= user.first_name + " " + user.last_name %></td>
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106735+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:         <tr>
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106737+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:           <td><%= user.email %></td>
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106737+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:           <td>
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106738+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:             <% if follow = user.follows.find_by(follows: user.id) %>
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106742+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/follows/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_follows_index_html_erb___1812592661839220487_70215972087760'
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106741+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/follows/index.html.erb:13:in `block in _app_views_follows_index_html_erb___1812592661839220487_70215972087760'
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106742+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:19:09.106743+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:24:13.636808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/follows" host=sn-sql.herokuapp.com request_id=fb1f9eee-890b-4227-8185-2ada91825cb6 fwd="141.225.80.1" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=1759
2016-11-28T22:24:13.634688+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/follows" for 141.225.80.1 at 2016-11-28 22:24:13 +0000
2016-11-28T22:24:13.637819+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by FollowsController#index as HTML
2016-11-28T22:24:13.642862+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mUser Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users"[0m
2016-11-28T22:24:13.645429+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered follows/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.4ms)
2016-11-28T22:24:13.645666+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647633+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647634+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647635+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <tbody>
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647636+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <% @users.try(:each) do |user| %>
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647637+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:         <tr>
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647637+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:           <td><%= user.first_name + " " + user.last_name %></td>
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647638+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:           <td><%= user.email %></td>
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647639+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:           <td>
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647639+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:             <% if follow = user.follows.find_by(follows: user.id) %>
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647640+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/follows/index.html.erb:13:in `block in _app_views_follows_index_html_erb___1812592661839220487_70215972087760'
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647641+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/follows/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_follows_index_html_erb___1812592661839220487_70215972087760'
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647642+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:24:13.647642+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:28:05.898802+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/" for 54.80.172.253 at 2016-11-28 22:28:05 +0000
2016-11-28T22:28:05.900540+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by NewsFeedController#index as HTML
2016-11-28T22:28:05.903485+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (1.4ms)
2016-11-28T22:28:05.904672+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mPost Load (0.8ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
2016-11-28T22:28:05.907075+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
2016-11-28T22:28:05.913989+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (9.0ms)
2016-11-28T22:28:05.914213+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered news_feed/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.3ms)
2016-11-28T22:28:05.914387+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915476+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915478+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915479+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:             </div>
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915480+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:             <div class="panel-body">
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915481+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:               <p><%= post.post_text %></p>
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915484+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:               <% if like = post.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) %>
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915485+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:                   <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Unlike'.html_safe, like, method: 'delete',class: ""  %>
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915486+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:               <% else %>
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915487+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:                   <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like'.html_safe, likes_path({post_id: post.id}), method: 'post',class: ""  %>
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915488+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_posts__post_html_erb__2305306643930163929_70215970144600'
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915489+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/news_feed/index.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_news_feed_index_html_erb__1204754539652968054_70215970424660'
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915490+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/news_feed/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_news_feed_index_html_erb__1204754539652968054_70215970424660'
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915491+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:28:05.915491+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-28T22:28:05.907994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=sn-sql.herokuapp.com request_id=85b21e2a-cdc7-4bfe-a3b5-8ff1ca1a460e fwd="54.80.172.253" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=277
```

Not sure what is going on since it work completely fine on my local server. Not sure what any of this means in the logs. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First off you should try to get used to reading logs as it's one of the primary things you'll need to get good at for debugging if you start developing rails applications.

They logs tell you what there error is here

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
```

Basically saying you're trying to add `nil` to something, which clearly doesn't make sense, hence the error. If you then look at the block below you can see you're trying to add a users first and last names here

```
<td><%= user.first_name + " " + user.last_name %></td>
```

So that user is missing either a first or last name. So all you need is a conditional to make sure both exist before you add them, like

```
<% if user.first_name && user.last_name %>
  <td><%= user.first_name + " " + user.last_name %></td>

  whatever else...
<% end %>
```

You also another error here

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

telling you something similar. Try figuring out where that error is coming from on your own since, as I said, being able to debug your own code is essential to development, regardless of language